# how to set abc.properties as log4j2 configuartion file in classpath

Tags: log4j2

I am migrating from log4j1 to log4j2 and i have a filename as abc.properties which i need to set as log4j configuration file in classpath. I tried with 
-Dlog4j.configurationFile=abc.properties,but no use?Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 0):

If the file is on classpath, you can set the location in code -

```
org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.Configurator.initialize(null, "abc.properties");
```

Set file path using above statement before using `Logger`.

Comment: the above code is not working... Ideally i need to use the properties in abc.properties as log4j2 configuration

Comment: what you do mean by - i need to use the properties in abc.properties as log4j2 configuration

Comment: Issue solved by passing log4j properties from a file as system properties